# Override twitter-bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a button with bootstrap, something like:

```
<a href="" ng-click="controller.refresh()" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-repeat bootstrap-refresh"></a>
```

I want to disable the style change when the button is hovered or click. I figured I could do this by overriding `btn-default:focus` or `btn:focus` but I also have other `<a>` tags styled as buttons that I would like to keep the effects of click or focus. Is there a way that I could just override the standard bootstrap css in just this case?

Answer (score 0):

add an id to this particular

```
<a href="" ng-click="controller.refresh()" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-repeat bootstrap-refresh" id="overrideBS"></a>
```

then add this css

```
#overrideBS:focus {
   //whatever unique properties you want
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression thats what he was asking for.  if he wants more than one use a class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

Add your own class `myclass`, then set `myclass:focus` with whatever changes your need adding `!important` at the end of the overridden value.